# Silverlight 3 making content size to Page size

Tags: silverlight, telerik-scheduler

When this page loads the *RadScheduler* control does not render fully on the screen so the bottom half is not visible. How can I make it so that it sizes to the remaining space in the Page window?

```
<navigation:Page>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ria:DomainDataSource />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="header row" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Label" />                        

        <telerikScheduler:RadScheduler Height="Auto">        
        </telerikScheduler:RadScheduler>

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:-

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ria:DomainDataSource />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="header row" />

    <TextBlock Text="Label" Grid.Row="1" />                        

    <telerikScheduler:RadScheduler Grid.Row="2" />

</Grid>
```